# Find expression at start of line or after a punctuation

Tags: java, regex

This has been bothering me for the past few days and I can't seem to find the answer. Consider the following:

I have a string called `"options"` which is in the form:

```
"xxx=true&yxxx=true&zzz=false"
```

(yes, like an URL query).

I have pattern matchers set up like so:

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("xxx=true");
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("yxxx=true");
Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("zzz=true");
```

My problem comes with differentiating between the second and first pattern, since pattern1 finds a match in the `yxxx=true` case since it contains the `"xxx=true"` string. I've looked everywhere, and could get away with splitting the first pattern to `"&xxx=true"` and `"^xxx=true"` to cover the "start of line" and every other case, but I just know there must be some other way to do this.

Comment: You could `split("&")` and then `split("=")` each valid result, though maybe it's kinda messy.

Comment: You might be after [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), as & is not a word-character - or just split on &, as suggested by @Zircon.

Comment: @Zircon yeah, I have considered splitting, but where would be the fun in that? ;D I just know there must be a way to create a regex that looks for either an "&" or a start of line. My pride is on the line here, I can't let this beat me.

Comment: Fun is...fun and all, but I like to put the fun in functional.

Comment: You can use: `(?<=&|^)xxx=true(?=&|$)`

Comment: @Zircon I know, I know, but this is for a personal project and I like going out of my way to find alternative solutions to simple problems since sometimes it comes in handy :)

Comment: That much I understand. It might be good to learn the regex solution to this problem, since Patterns can be very useful.

Comment: @anubhava Oh lord, that works perfectly! I tried (&|^) previously and it didn't work. All the java api says about expressions of the type (?<=X) is "X, via zero-width positive lookbehind", I would have never tried that. Thanks!

Comment: @anubhava beat me to the answer! :)
My go-to resource for regex is http://regexr.com/ See Reference > Groups & Lookaround.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use negative lookbehind matching

So your pattern should be

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(?<!y)xxx=true");
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("yxxx=true");
Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("zzz=true");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters and values contain only lowercase letters, then you can use a single pattern

```
(?:^|&)([a-z]+)=([a-z]+)(?:&|$)
```

with multiline matching to match parameters and values, then iterate over all matches and check what parameter you've matched this time. This will work even if parameter names or their order change.

Another alternative is to parse this parameter string as URL parameter string.